# Kendo Grid Inline MultiSelect - Posted Values

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect, kendo-editor

I'm replicating the functionality very close to what's seen here.  https://onabai.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/kendoui-multiselect-in-a-grid-yes-we-can/

I have Kendo grid with an inline multiselect editor field.  I have a datasource.sync() event kicked off on change of that multiselect.  The issue I'm having is how the data is arranged in the post variables.

I'm using FireBug in FireFox.  I can set a function to view the values in my multiselect field like this at the sync() event.

`console.log(this.value());`

This would be for a string array field I have called "RoleCode".  Anyway, the console log displays the values as they should, for example

`A, OU`

However, when I look in the Post call to my controller and at the parameters, I see the RoleCode field is duplicated, which is why my controller doesn't recognize the method signature.  For example, this is what I see in FireBug...

```
ID  123
Field1  TextFromField1
RoleCode[1][RoleCode]  OU
RoleCode[]  A
```

Any idea how I should set this up so the post parameters are usable?

**UPDATE**

For now I just altered the update function to send the multiselect values as a comma separated string.  I can deal with them in the controller.  I don't really like this setup, but until I find how to get the posted values to send correctly, this is what I'm going with.

```
    update: {
            url: "Home/GridUpdate",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function () {
                //Grid does not post multiselect array correctly, need to convert to a string
                var rolesString = $("#gridRoleList").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString();
                return { rolesString: rolesString };
            },
            complete: function (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    refreshGrid();
                }, 300);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                // notify the data source that the request succeeded
                options.success(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                // notify the data source that the request failed
                options.error(result);
            }
        },
```

**UPDATE 2**

Actually that's not a good idea because if I edit another field in the grid, I get a js error because the multiselect is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.  On the change event of the editor function, I updated the value of the model with the value of the multiselect.  Then the data posts correctly as a string array like this.

```
ID  123
Field1  TextFromField1
RoleCode[]  A
RoleCode[]  OU
```

My grid editor function

```
function roleMultiSelectEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input id = "gridRoleList" name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            dataTextField: "RoleCode",
            dataValueField: "RoleCode",
            autoBind: true,    
            change: function (e) {
                //Applies the value of the multiselect to the model.RoleCode field
                //Necessary to correctly post values to controller
                options.model.RoleCode = this.value();
                processGridMultiSelectChange();
            },
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: baseUrl + "api/DropDownData/RoleList",
                    },
                }
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue can be resolved by sending the data after serializing it

Read action - using MVC Wrapper

```
.Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Home").Data("serialize"))
```

JS Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function serialize(data) {
    debugger;
    for (var property in data) {
        if ($.isArray(data[property])) {
            serializeArray(property, data[property], data);
        }
    }
}

function serializeArray(prefix, array, result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ($.isPlainObject(array[i])) {
            for (var property in array[i]) {
                result[prefix + "[" + i + "]." + property] = array[i][property];
            }
        }
        else {
            result[prefix + "[" + i + "]"] = array[i];
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

[Please refer here for complete source code](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-multiselect-in-grid)

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is what I need, but I'm not using the MVC wrappers.  Any idea how to run the data through these functions on the datasource.sync() event, or in the update function of the transport?

Comment: You can use the transport.read.data function to send additional parameters from JS, Please refer the Kendo UI documentation here. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data